# Cloned 250GB SSD to a 2TB NVME SSD and now the target drive only has 250GB and I cannot resize

Tags: hard-drive, clone, disk-cloning, acronis-diskdirector

I just used a hardware cloning device. Where I just press a button and it clones the source to the target, but now the target is only 250GB and I can't resize the partition to take up the rest of the 2TB. As you can see in the Acronis Disk Director software, it doesn't show the unallocated space I can resize the last partition with.

What went wrong? Or should I just be using a software type cloning tool like Macrium Reflect?

[image]

Comment: I'm using a paid version of Acronis Disk Director 12 and it doesn't see the full size for whatever reason.

Comment: First think check with other disk tools to see what they see. Try Windows Disk Management and command line Diskpart, and you can also try with MiniTool Partition Wizard.

Comment: Ok looks like the *Windows Disk Management* did the trick. It saw the unallocated space and I was able to extend the partition to take up the full amount of free space. Thx! lesson learned don't rely on Acronis even if you paid for it.

Comment: Just wondering, did it show it as "unallocated" or as some other type?

Comment: Who is the manufacturer of the drive? Which model is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one application doesn't seem to see the available unused space, the first thing to try would be some other disk management tools, and see what they say, and if they allow you to see/expand the partition to the unused space.

Some tools you can try with:

- Windows built-in **Disk Management** took
- Windows command link `diskpart` tool
- **MiniTool Partition Wizard** free version